# Smartsheet - get data from Teradata or/and Power BI

Tags: smartsheet-api

I know it is reversed logic to get data from Power BI into smarthseet but is it possible?

Also, can I get connection from Teradata to smartsheet?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the systems that you're interested in getting data *from* have APIs that enable you to retrieve the data you need, the scenario you've describe would be possible. For example, you could use the [Power BI API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) to retrieve data from Power BI and then use the [Smartsheet API](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/) to add that data to Smartsheet.